# g++ 4.9.0 allows us to use operator delete[](void*, size_t) with placement allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++

i'm using g++ 4.9.0 and N3797 working draft. I've written the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void* operator new[](size_t t, size_t)
    {
        cout << "allocation" << endl;
        return ::operator new[](t);
    }

    void operator delete[](void *p, size_t t)
    {
        cout << "deallocation" << endl;
        :: operator delete[](p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new (90) A[5];
    delete [] a;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abb5ff8a08d97afb)

The example must reflect the following footnote rule from the section 3.7.4.2/2:

> The global operator delete[] with exactly two parameters, the second
>   of which has type std::size_t, is a usual deallocation function.37
>
> 37) This deallocation function precludes use of an allocation function
>   void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t) as a placement allocation
>   function

But it doesn't. It is a bug or footnote is just a recommendation for implementors?

Comment: What if they belong to the global namespace instead of `struct A`?

Comment: @aschepler Hmm... how to invoke two-parameter deallocation function from the global namespace via delete-expression? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2525df8e20abc2ec

Comment: @aschepler I have received completely the same result. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09201625d1046c09

Comment: You don't invoke a placement deallocation function of any sort via a delete-expression.  They are only used for exceptions during a new-expression.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Note that g++ [doesn't support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) global sized deallocation yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is illegal and the compiler should have emitted a diagnostic. From §5.3.4 [expr.new]/p22, emphasis added:

> A declaration of a placement deallocation function matches the
>   declaration of a placement allocation function if it has the same
>   number of parameters and, after parameter transformations (8.3.5), all
>   parameter types except the first are identical. If the lookup finds a
>   single matching deallocation function, that function will be called;
>   otherwise, no deallocation function will be called. **If the lookup
>   finds the two-parameter form of a usual deallocation function
>   (3.7.4.2) and that function, considered as a placement deallocation
>   function, would have been selected as a match for the allocation
>   function, the program is ill-formed.** For a non-placement allocation
>   function, the normal deallocation function lookup is used to find the
>   matching deallocation function (5.3.5) [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>      // Placement allocation function:
>     static void* operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t);
>     // Usual (non-placement) deallocation function:
>     static void operator delete(void*, std::size_t);
> };
> S* p = new (0) S; // ill-formed: non-placement deallocation function matches
>                   // placement allocation function
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Clang [generates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed62b27b9283ee1a) an error on your code.

However, note that unlike global `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`, two-parameter `operator delete` and `operator delete[]` that are class members are not necessarily a usual deallocation function (§3.7.4.2 [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/p2):

> If a class `T` has a member deallocation function named `operator delete`
>   with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual
>   deallocation function. If class `T` does not declare such an `operator delete`
>   but does declare a member deallocation function named `operator delete`
>   with exactly two parameters, the second of which has type
>   `std::size_t`, then this function is a usual deallocation function.
>   Similarly, if a class `T` has a member deallocation function named
>   `operator delete[]` with exactly one parameter, then that function is
>   a usual (non-placement) deallocation function. If class T does not
>   declare such an `operator delete[]` but does declare a member
>   deallocation function named `operator delete[]` with exactly two
>   parameters, the second of which has type `std::size_t`, then this
>   function is a usual deallocation function.

Thus, unlike the global deallocation functions, if you declare a member `operator delete[] (void *)`, then `operator delete[] (void *, std::size_t)` is no longer a usual deallocation function but a placement deallocation function:

```
struct A
{
    void* operator new[](size_t t, size_t)
    {
        cout << "allocation" << endl;
        return ::operator new[](t);
    }

    void operator delete[](void *p)
    {
        cout << "deallocation - usual" << endl;
        :: operator delete[](p);
    }
    void operator delete[](void *p, size_t t)
    {
        cout << "deallocation - placement" << endl;
        :: operator delete[](p);
    }
};
```

And clang [no longer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93caeaa8f890609b) reports an error on this code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting undefined behavior. I think if the constructor fails and the array has to be deallocated it's not possible to distinguish between the right placement delete function and the sized delete function.

Comment: It is a bit unclear. There is no something about UB in the sec. 3.7.4.2. Would you add a bit more clarification?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Not all undefined behavior is specifically called out in the spec. If the spec simply fails to describe a situation then what happens is also 'undefined behavior'. But as the other answer shows the spec actually does cover this situation, and specifically labels it ill-formed.